# Let $f(x)$ be differentiable over $\left[0,1\right]$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Prove that $f'(x) - 2f(x)$ has a zero in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

for a final exam review for Real Analysis, the following problem is asked:

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function over $[0,1]$. Suppose that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Prove that $f'(x) - 2f(x)$ must have a zero inside of $(0,1)$.

My initial idea was to use Rolle's Theorem, since both endpoints are equal to 0 in order to show that $f'(x)$ must have a zero, but I'm not sure how to go from there. I've also tried to use the Cauchy Mean-Value Theorem by letting $g(x)$ be a function with $g'(x) = f'(x) - 2f(x)$, but I wasn't quite sure how to use that to prove the statement.  We can't use any integration as the last chapter we've done is on differentiation. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Whenever you see $f'-2f$ think $e^{-2x}$. Let $\phi(x)= e^{-2x} f(x)$. How would Rolle's theorem help here?

Comment: @copper.hat, that method is more "differential equations style" though, and is a great perspective, but would it be more likely that another technique is desired in the given context of what is probably an undergraduate introductory analysis course? I'm just asking because I'm curious myself. Of course a student in this course should have had ODEs probably.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the suggestion. I see how this could lead to a solution, but based off of the nature of the course and the previous exams I'm not entirely sure if we're allowed to use a proof of this kind, and instead have to work out proofs derived from general theorems that we've learned in the course. I'll work with this for now and see if I can find anything out from it relating to the theorems that we've used. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know how else I would approach this with elementary tools.

Comment: Are you sure, that $f$ is just differentiable and not continuously differentiable? If $f$ is just differentiable, then $f'$ can be discontinuous and I think the statement will become wrong.

Comment: @copper.hat Your proposed solution is completely elementary. I think you should post an answer, and if there are howls of protest, we can look for something else.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt did you read the post of copper.hat?

Comment: @zhw.: I am curious if there is another elementary way :-).

Comment: The $2$ here is a red herring. Almost any function would do.

Comment: @Hans can you expand on this a bit?

Comment: Given an arbitrary integrable function $g$, apply Rolle's theorem to $fe^{-\int_0^x g}$.

Comment: Your initial idea is correct. And all question of this kind is basically solve a simple ODE. This is surely the natural and elementary thought.